# gRPC go: apply interceptor at service level

Tags: grpc, grpc-go

The gRPC interceptor is applied to the server through `ServerOption`. see the [doc](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/tree/master/examples/features/interceptor)
How can I apply interceptor at service level. For example, I may only need to apply the authenticator interceptor for protected service. Is this possible in go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A gRPC Go interceptor receives a [StreamServerInfo](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/grpc#StreamServerInfo) (or a [UnaryServerInfo](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/grpc#UnaryServerInfo)) param that contains, among other things, the service and method name of the call. You can use that to filter interceptor behavior based on service/method.

Answer (score 2):

In addition of previous answer by eric, you can do something like :

```
type key int

const (
    sessionIDKey key = iota
)

var (
    needTobeAllocate = [1]string{"allocate"}
)

func run() {
    // server option 
    opts := []grpc.ServerOption{}
    opts = append(opts, grpc.UnaryInterceptor(unaryInterceptor))
}


func unaryInterceptor(ctx context.Context, req interface{}, info *grpc.UnaryServerInfo, handler grpc.UnaryHandler) (interface{}, error) {
    if checkAllocate(info.FullMethod) {
        ctx = context.WithValue(ctx, sessionIDKey, "testsession")   
    }

    return handler(ctx, req)
}

func checkAllocate(method string) bool {
    for _, v := range needTobeAllocate {
        if strings.Contains(strings.ToLower(method), v) {
            return true
        }
    }

    return false
}
```